# Changing the color of the path in Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, color

I would like the `CasebashMac:bfgenv chris$` part of the following line to appear in a different color in my terminal.

```
CasebashMac:bfgenv chris$ python
```

Answer (score 8):

I set the PS1 variable in my `.bashrc` to achieve this.

- Open Terminal
- `[editorofchoice] ~/.bashrc`
- Add a line with the following:

`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`

- Save the `.bashrc`
- Exit Terminal and re-open. You should now have a green prompt.

Comment: Where is this bashrc file?

Comment: @Casebash It should be in you home folder for your user account. If it does not exist, which often it doesn't, just create it.

Comment: “.bashrc” won’t be there by default, and since it has a DOT, you won’t see it in finder (unless you have told it to show invisible files). Therefore it’s usually safe to use “vi” or “pico" to edit the file, because if it doesn’t exist, it will create it.

Comment: It works if I run the command using export, but not in my .bashrc file. `CasebashMac:~ chris$ cat ~/.bashrc
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`

Comment: @Casebash. I am not sure what he problem is. I copied that straight out of the `.bashrc` on my machine. The actual PS1 line I got from my Ubuntu Server since I wanted both to be the same. Also make sure you exit both the terminal and quit terminal and then reopen.

Comment: @Diago: Maybe there is another config file somewhere with higher priority?

Comment: @Casebash. Doubt it. All customizations I have done to the terminal and my profile has always been in `.bashrc`. I have double checked on my side and it is correct. I am not very clued up on how it works, I really just applied what I know about Linux to get it to work for me since the rules are the same. I am not sure why it's not working in your case.

Comment: There is why this works (an explanation about the values that go on PS1): http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/

Answer (score 2):

The terminal app does not actually change the colours, this is controlled by the shell that is being run. The default shell is bash and controlling colours is done by altering the prompt. There are many tutorials and other documents on the web to tell you more.

One guide to customising the prompt is from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/)

Comment: Please include an example directly into your answer.

Comment: @Hillside - not really as I think too broad for an answer

Comment: @nohillside but then again see my answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59480/how-to-change-the-color-and-format-of-the-static-host-path-user-string-in-the-te?rq=1 - OK we have a duplicate - my answer there is much better than here and the the answer here is not that good. Close this as a duplicate?