# How to change the color and format of the static host/path/user string in the Terminal or iTerm?

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm

Example:

```
cookie:~ j$ date
Sun Aug  5 02:14:29 CEST 2012
cookie:~ j$
```

Just as it's pasted here, all three lines are of the same color. I would like to have "`cookie:~ j$`" or at least part of the string be of a different color than the rest.

I know that I can specifically enable color coding for specific applications like `ls` or `git`, but I haven't found anything like this.

Is there a way to change the coloring and format of the static host/path/user string in the Terminal or iTerm?

Comment: This might be useful for you? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/how-can-i-configure-mac-terminal-to-have-color-ls-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for us [customizing the prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt) in the bash shell. Many articles on the web including this [one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/).

This is basically done by setting the variable PS1 e.g.

```
PS1="\[\033[35m\]\t\[\033[m\]-\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
```

gives for user mark on machine flat

[image]

This includes \t as time, \u as user \h as hostname and \w current working directory

The \[ then \octal number \] send commands to the terminal , in this case acting as an xterm and sets the colours.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this page for instructions on how to do this
http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/customising-the-terminal.php

Comment: Not an answer. Consider writing an answer rather than just posting a link.