# How can I change PS1 in zsh to show the current directory in addition to the path?

Tags: macos, iterm, zsh

On macOS 13.1 (22C65) and using zsh in iTerm2 I'm trying to customize my shell.

I've made decent progress with my POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_CLASSES:

- the path is white
- all my BACGROUNDS are dark

I hope to specify a dir with a light BACKGROUND and so set a black FOREGROUND, but it only changed the icon and seperator color, not the text color, see below:

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_CLASSES=(
       '~/work(|/*)'               WORK      ''
       '~/Projets/Android(|/*)'    ANDROID   ''
       '~/Projets(|/*)'            PROJETS   ''
```

base 1 :

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_PROJETS_BACKGROUND=160
```

result :

[image]

problem :

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_ANDROID_BACKGROUND=148
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_ANDROID_FOREGROUND=232
```

the result : (all text should be black)

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing and why this behaves like that ?

Comment: Please use the edit to fix version numbers [and shell if my guesses](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/59517/5472) were not on the mark.

Comment: _current directory **in addition to the path**_ : What "path" are you refering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change the color of the actual path as well, you also have to set `SHORTENED_FOREGROUND` and `ANCHOR_FOREGROUND`because p10k uses shortened and anchor fallback:

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_[DIR_NAME]_SHORTENED_FOREGROUND=[color]  
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_[DIR_NAME]_ANCHOR_FOREGROUND=[color]
```

In my case it would be :

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_CLASSES=(
       '~/work(|/*)'               WORK      ''
       '~/Projets/Android(|/*)'    ANDROID   ''
       '~/Projets(|/*)'            PROJETS   ''

typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_ANDROID_BACKGROUND=148
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_ANDROID_FOREGROUND=232
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_ANDROID_SHORTENED_FOREGROUND=232  
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_ANDROID_ANCHOR_FOREGROUND=232
```

check this [github issue](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/2227#event-8791653081) for more details.

thanks to romkatv for the help.